# Motion Blur direction identification DirectX

Tags: directx, shader, cg, motion-blur

I am storing velocity information in the texture. As texture can only have color values in range {0, 1} How should I determine the direction of the velocity ? 
One solution is to create another texture which stores only the direction information for the velocity but it will be very costly.
Any thoughts pls ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 4 channels .. r, g, b and a ... use each channel to represent on of x,y and z.  Kinda like a normal map.  For the alpha channel you can encode using an [RGBE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBE_image_format) style format.  Effectively you store a normalised vector in the R,G and B channels and then store the exponent in the A/E channel.

Edit: Furthermore using something like a spherical environment map you could encode the direction vector as an x and y index and thus save a channel.